# Poisson equation with radial function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, poissons-equation

while reading the book, I ran into a problem with the partial differential equation. The problem is following: Find positive radially symmetric function $w$ such that $-\Delta w = \Phi (r) \ (r=|x|)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ and $\lim_{r \to \infty}w(r)=0$. The book says that
$$w(r)= K-\int_{0}^{r}\zeta^{1-N} \int_{0}^{\zeta}\sigma^{N-1}\Phi(\sigma)d\sigma d\zeta,$$
where
$$
K=\int_{0}^{\infty}\zeta^{1-N} \int_{0}^{\zeta}\sigma^{N-1}\Phi(\sigma)d\sigma d\zeta.
$$
I thought the solution would be a convolution of the fundamental solution of the Laplace equation with the right side as in the Poisson equation but it did not work. I need a tip on how to go about it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you forgot a condition on $\Phi$ to ensure $w$ is positive.

Comment: You are right, $\Phi$ was defined on previous pages as $\max_{|x|=r} \rho(x)$, where $\rho \in L^{\infty}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$, $\rho \ge 0$ and $\rho \not \equiv 0$.

Comment: Recall $\operatorname{div}\circ\operatorname{grad}\varphi=r^{1-N}\partial_r(r^{N-1}\partial_r \varphi)+r^{-2}\Delta_{S^{n-1}}\varphi$.  Kill the spherical part and integrate the radial part.

Comment: I did it today but was not sure about the spherical part. It is zero because in the spherical part we have a constant function, am I right?